# Clojure extracting the values from the vector of maps

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure

Is there a way to extract all the values from a vector of maps?

```
(def vector-of-maps [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])
```

Because

```
(vals vector-of-maps)
```

doesn't work of course.

I am trying to apply a function on every map in a vector, therefore I need every map, ie. {:a 1 :b 2}, and then {:a 3 :b 4}

Comment: Please show expected output. Your answer is at variance with the others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(mapcat vals vector-of-maps)
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do. Because maps are not ordered, you might see the values in different order than in the literal map representation:

```
(mapcat vals vector-of-maps)
```

Comment: LOL, I was a little faster ;-)

Comment: `(distinct (mapcat vals vector-of-maps))`?

Comment: @galdre, Since we don't know expected output, we can only guess.